# ListPopupWindow items not drawing correctly

Tags: android, listview, popupwindow

I have a ListPopupWindow that is being populated from a custom adapter. The custom xml consists of 2 textviews and a LinearLayout. The custom adapter populates the textviews and instantiates a custom view that draws a thumbnail sized vector based graphic. The custom view is then added to the Linear Layout.

The problem is that the first row displayed always has the wrong graphic displayed. It is sometimes the graphic from another row, sometimes half of it is the correct graphic, half from the wrong row. I've also noticed that if the list has enough rows in it to scroll, the items at the bottom of the list have the same problem when scrolling.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Custom List Adapter:

```
public class PageSearchListAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter
{
    int _height = 130;
  int _width = 130;

  Cursor c;
  Context context;

  // Constructor, here we store any parameters we need in class variables 
  //
    public PageSearchListAdapter(Context context, 
                                 int layout, 
                                 Cursor c,
                                 String[] from, 
                                 int[] to) 
    {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);

    this.c = c;
    this.context=context;

    }

    // Main view method - the views in query_list_item are populated here
    //
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
  {
    // Make sure we have a view to work with
    //
    if(convertView == null)
        convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.query_list_item, null);

    View row = convertView; 

    // go to the correct row in the cursor
    //
    c.moveToPosition(position);

    // Get the views that need populating
    //
    TextView PageNum = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Page_Num);
    LinearLayout pic = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Page_Canvas);
    TextView Date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Page_Date);

    // Set the values
    //
    PageNum.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("PageNum")));
    Date.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Timestamp")));

    List<Point> Vectors = new ArrayList<Point>();

    byte[] asBytes = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("Vectors"));

    ..
    .. removed code to Convert Blob to array of 'Vector' records ...
    ..

    // Draw the page
    //

    NotePadPage npPage = new NotePadPage(context, Vectors);

    npPage.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(_width, _height));

    pic.addView(npPage);

    return(row);
  }

}
```

NotePadPage class:

```
    // Adapter to display a custom list item in a list view
    //
    public class NotePadPage extends View
    {

        int _height = 130;
        int _width = 130;

        Bitmap _bitmap;
        Canvas _canvas;

        Paint _paint;

        List<Point> _Vectors = new ArrayList<Point>();


        public NotePadPage(Context context, List<Point> Vectors) 
        {
            super(context);

            _Vectors = Vectors;

            _paint = new Paint();
            _paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            _paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) 
        {
            _height = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            _width = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

            setMeasuredDimension(_width, _height);

            _bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(_width, _height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            _canvas = new Canvas(_bitmap);        
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
        {
            float yRatio = 1092/ _height;
            float xRatio = 800 / _width;

            Point lastPoint = null;

            for (Point point : _Vectors) 
            {
                switch (point.Type)
                {
                    case Start:
                    {
                        lastPoint = point;
                        break;
                    }
                    case Midpoint:
                    case End:
                    {
                        canvas.drawLine(lastPoint.x / xRatio, lastPoint.y/ yRatio, point.x / xRatio, point.y/ yRatio, _paint);
                        lastPoint = point;                  
                    }
                }
            }

        }    

    }
```

Referenced Classes:

```
    public class Point 
    {
        public float x, y;

        public PointType Type;      
    }

    public enum PointType 
    { 
        Start, 
        Midpoint , 
        End;

    }
```

XML for List row:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"    >

        <TextView        
            android:id="@+id/Page_Num"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"        
            android:text="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Page_Canvas"
            android:layout_width="130dip"
            android:layout_height="130dip"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Page_Num">
        </LinearLayout>    

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Page_Date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"        
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Page_Canvas">

        </TextView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: are you drawing charts there? Or predefined images? If images are simply taken from the DB then this article is your case mate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532742/problem-creating-a-drawable-from-a-sqlite-blob

Comment: I'm taking drawing points stored in a blob in the database and just drawing them in the OnDraw event. I know the data is stored ok, as it is accessed and drawn in other parts of the app with no problem.